# Phonegap how to download and open pdf file in android app

Tags: android, cordova

recently i am working on a android apps build in phonegap, i am quite new with mobile development and this i smy first appsbut, and i am stuck when try to download some documents (pdf, doc, jpg) to local storage and open it, after search through google and i tried to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13375234/how-to-open-downloaded-file-pdf-zip-docx-etc-in-phonegap-app).

I followed the exact code in the example and below is how i call the plugins:

```
window.plugins.downloader.downloadFile(url,'/sdcard/download/', 'test.pdf', true, downloadOkCallbak, downloadErCallbak);
    window.plugins.pdfViewer.showPdf('/sdcard/download/test.pdf');
```

The url is my remote file, when i execute it, i got error: "TypeError: window.plugins is undefined". Anyone help is appreciated.

**[update]** My code of showPdf function:

```
public String showPdf(String fileName) {

    File file = new File(fileName);

    if (file.exists()) {
        try {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


            //intent.setData(Uri.parse(fileName));
            this.ctx.startActivity(intent);
            return "";
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("PdfViewer: Error loading url "+fileName+":"+ e.toString());
            return e.toString();
        }            

    }else{
        return "file not found";
    }

}
```

**[Update 2]** I got below error in web console: Uncaught ReferrenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined at ...

What could be the issue?

Comment: Are you having your classes that extend DroidGap and Plugin classes? Mind if you share some code of your showPdf function.

Comment: Yes, it extends plugin class, it's too long to past the code here, i will put it in below reply.

Comment: sorry i can't paste my code below, i updated my question to include the code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem as the OP and many unsuccessful approaches later I came to the following solution (tested with Cordova 3.1.0-3.3.0 & Samsung Galaxy S3 & iOS 7):

### Solution

First, get the file by [requesting the file system](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) and then download it from your server with [fileTransfer.download()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download). After completing the download call the FileOpener (which will open a pop up where to choose from apps like Adobe Reader). Note: Make sure to include the FileTransfer feature via CLI/Terminal: **cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file**

- Navigate to your project folder
- Open CLI/Terminal and type in: **`cordova plugin add https://github.com/don/FileOpener.git`**
- After successful download and storage of your file on the device (see above) you open it with: **`window.plugins.fileOpener.open("file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.example.application/document.doc")`** or the appropriate path on iOS.

That's it! Good luck!

Comment: This plugin does exactly what I want, no more struggling with bad or incomplete documentation. This answer is very helpful +1!

Comment: - I found this plugin very nice for handling file opening https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2 
- "File Transfer" Cordova plugin has been deprecated in favor of XMLHttpRequest, see https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Comment: Very useful doc on this page (write temporary/permanent files): https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've had these lines in your manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

You can find help here [How to download a pdf file in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368788/how-to-download-a-pdf-file-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I have that permissions set.  actually i am looking for a solution using phonegap + jquery mobile, which means i can call to download / open the pdf via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

You should install git and install file plugins(cordova 3.0+)

File and file transfer plugin

`$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer`

Ps. Try plugin fileOpener2

https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1117

Answer (score 0):

Try this to open any kind of documents from URL using following steps:

- install this plugin : cordova plugin add https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler
- use this code :

  handleDocumentWithURL(function() { console.log('success'); }, function(error) { console.log('failure'); if (error == 53) { console.log('No app that handles this file type.'); } }, 'http://www.example.com/path/to/document.pdf');

It works for me both on Android and IOS. I used it for open **images** and **PDF** files.

**Android** : It opens files using system apps if available, otherwise it give an error, which you can handle.

**IOS** : It opens files in popup like view with **Done** button and **Option** button.

**It doesn't show your docs URL.**

Source is available here : https://github.com/ti8m/DocumentHandler