# How to load a pdf file from URL with phonegap

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I have a JQuery mobile application and used phonegap/cordova Android to convert it to an apk,
I have a page which makes an ajax call with userid and password to a httpservice and retrieve a link to pdf file.

I want the user be able to open or download this file, the response result is a url like `www.site.com/results/4524dfdssd.pdf`,

i tried all methods discussed here but no success like Inappbrowser or FileTransfer any help please.

Comment: Android webview doesnot support PDFViewing

Comment: I know so i search for a another solution, if i can open the link in the system browser or download the file.

Comment: System is different from mobile. You can use pdf-viewers to view the pdf from mobile. For example, MuPdf Viewer

Comment: The problem is not in viewing the pdf file, how can i make the system reach the file from its url?

Comment: you want to open in browser ? can you please be bit more clear

Comment: i want to make the user able to view the file by any way if view the file or download it

Comment: I know this is old and OP might have his answer by now, but for those still looking: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20965308/594992