# Unable to view pdf file using PhoneGap

Tags: jquery, cordova, pdf

I am trying to view a pdf that has been downloaded, but have no luck displaying it.

This is my code for downloading and displaying a file. When I try to open the file I just get an alert saying unable to view file.

**jQuery**

```
// Download edition's pdf file
function downloadFile(filename){
    var localDir = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
    // Validate if file exist before download
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(localDir + filename, function(){
        ShowPDF(localDir + filename);
    }, function(){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile(
                "index.html", {create: true, exclusive: false}, 
                function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
                    //var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("index.html","");
                    var localDir = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    fileTransfer.download(
                        path + filename,
                        localDir + filename,
                        function(theFile) {
                            ShowPDF(theFile.toURI());
                            console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                            console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                            console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                            console.log(error);
                        }
                    );
            }, fail);
    }, fail);
    });
};

// Show downloaded pdf
function ShowPDF(filePath){
    window.open(filePath, '_system', 'location=yes')
};
```

**EDIT:**
I just realized that this part will also download the file using the browser and then you can view the downloaded file.

```
window.open(path + filename, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

I need to validate if the file has already been downloaded before displaying the local file.

**Update**

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271052/phonegap-how-to-download-and-open-pdf-file-in-android-app/20965308#20965308) but still unable to view the local file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant Open PDF in cordova webview.
Try Phonegap [File Opener](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2) Plugin.

Comment: I am currently using the fileOpener plugin but still no success

Comment: Please be sure that you have at least one pdf reader exist in your device

Comment: Yes I do have readers on my phone. What I think could be the issue is that the location where the file is stored do not have permission perhaps to read the file. I am investigating this issue